# Selenium ignore if element not present

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have the below code for my selenium, where I need to click on carousel icons and get all the images one by one, but sometimes that carousel doesn't have more than one image and thus arrow icon is not present and clickable.

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(".arrow-icon "))).click();
```

How can I handle the exception where the element is not clickable ??

Comment: Try with FluentWait, add the exception you got in ignoring() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to fix it

1. Use `findElements` that would return a `list of web element` if found otherwise `size` of `list` will be `0`

   ```
    try {
        if (driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".arrow-icon ")).size() > 0 ) {
            System.out.println("Size is > 0 so there must be at least one web element, do some interaction below like click etc");
            new WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(".arrow-icon "))).click();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Size is 0, so web element must not be present, do something here that would make it available");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
   ```
2. Use risky code inside directly `try`

   ```
    try {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(".arrow-icon "))).click();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, after adding the if check, its getting inside the loop, but still i am getting the error on the line click --org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: .arrow-icon  (tried for 40 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: I see a space there in css `.arrow-icon ` is it intentional?

Comment: Yes, i tried without space, its not able to work even for carousel where more than one images are present, so added space.

Comment: Adding to this, i wrote code to click on the carousel first, and then click on arrow icon, this solved the problem